# FLASK PUT Curl Command : {"message": "Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'."}

Tags: python, json, http, flask, curl

I am following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xqJXDZvtogY

Everything is working until I write a curl command for a PUT request. The following error is displayed in my command prompt: **"Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'."**

My Python file App.py is:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse

app = Flask("VideoAPI")
api = Api(app)

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('title', required=True)


videos = {
    'video1' : {'title':'Hello world in python'},
    'video2' : {'title':'Why R is good'}
}

class Video(Resource):
    def get(self, video_id):
        if video_id=="all":
            return videos 
        return videos[video_id]
    
    def put(self, video_id):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        new_video = {'title': args['title']}
        videos[video_id] = new_video
        return {video_id: videos[video_id]}, 201

api.add_resource(Video, '/videos/<video_id>')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

my curl command: **curl http://localhost:5000/videos/video3 -d "title"="My New Video" -X PUT**

My versions: Werkzeug/3.0.1 Python/3.12.1

After researching and trying to solve, there have been suggestions that the curl command is not perfect and going well with the packages so I have tried the following curl commands and they have also resulted in an error.

1. **curl -i -X -PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"title":"MyNew Video"}' http://localhost:5000/videos/video3**
   error: 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED

What could be the issue?

Comment: `405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED` would mean your endpoint is not willing to accept PUT requests to begin with ...

Comment: that is weird, i have specified PUT in my App.py. Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: Remove the `-` from `-PUT`.

Comment: tried. does not work :( @KlausD. gives error: {"message": "The method is not allowed for the requested URL."}

Comment: Well, you seems to have multiple errors in your code and `curl` call. It is not the idea of Stack Overflow to clear them one by one in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of experimenting: the curl command which worked for me is:

```py
>curl http://localhost:5000/videos/video3 -d "{\"title\":\"titlename\"}" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X PUT
```